# install debian from hybrid standard CD

Tags: debian

I downloaded debian-live-8.1.0-i386-standard.iso
from http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0-live/i386/iso-hybrid/
and booted a system from it , logged in with "user" and password as "live". **NOW, When i got bash prompt, now what to type so that the "debian standard" installation starts to install on my hard disk?**

background note: i downloaded all other .iso (for example: debian-live-8.1.0-i386-mate-desktop.iso  ) from the same above directory url. And from all those .iso,  i could run the system as live and install also - ie, they are hybrid CD.
The standard iso works fine as live CD , but as it is hybrid CD too, so it should be able to start installation also.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is shortcut on your graphical environment or system menu which says something like "Install Debian to HDD" or something like that. I strongly recommend you to use that.

There is a way to install it via shell, but if you want it so hard, i can suggest you to consult with [the official documentaton](http://live.debian.net/manual/stable/html/live-manual.en.html)